# Rending produces black shadows

Tags: rendering

I am very new to Blender.

When I render using Cycles. I get a portion of my object that turns out black. Under evee it's normal.

[image]

I am not sure what other info to share to help with my problem.

I have reduced the form 4k to 2k tried GPU and CPU rendering to the same effect.

Thank you

Comment: Could be flipped normals

Comment: You might need to expand please. 

Also Opix run's.

Comment: select the black objects, go into edit mode with tab, select everything with A, then go to Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside or SHIFT N. Basically the renderer thinks these parts are the inside of the mesh, so it doesn't illuminate them

Comment: @Gorgious Just tried it. Still black 

Thanks for trying to help

Comment: This could also occur because of overlapping geometry by duplicate objects / mesh.
Try selecting one of those objects and hiding it or moving it around to see if there are multiple copies of the same object in the exact same place. If that doesn't work, try hiding or moving individual faces in Edit Mode.

Comment: @Adisage you nailed it. 

Stacked objects.....Feel stupid now.

Thank you and have a good weekend

Comment: Glad to be of help! Happy weekend to you too !
PS : Kindly upvote the comment ;)

Comment: I can't see how to up vote it. 

Help a brother do the right thing